# How to select all text in <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, selection

I want to make button, which will select all text in my p tag. Example of tag:

```
<p class="foo">
some text
<div>this div is child of p</div>
<div>one more row</div>
</p>
```

Also solution must be via window.getSelection() or similar but not jQuery.
I am trying do this by using selectNodeContents(el), but result was only first line.

Can anyone help me, because I can't figure this out.

*edit* code:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(txt);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Comment: You should post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic problem is, I think, that `<div>` elements cannot be children of `<p>` elements. Your `<p>` implicitly ends at the opening of the first `<div>`.

If you change the `<div>` elements to `<span>` then they'll be inside the `<p>`. The next problem you'll have to fix is that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list, not a single element, so the code has to take that into account:

```
  range.selectNodeContents(txt[0]);
```

[Here is a working CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/ynsjz)

Comment: I can change p with div. How then select all text?

Comment: I don't know what you mean; you cannot put a `<p>` inside another `<p>` either.  Check the linked CodePen in my updated answer.

Comment: Pointy, can u help, with node list. I have a lots of element p, but want to select text of only one p. How can i solve it?

Comment: @Roman well, first you have to decide what it is about that one `<p>` that makes it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to structure your HTML better as nested a `<div>` inside a `<p>` is invalid but:

http://jsfiddle.net/hge2Lp0p/1/

Using answer from: [Select text in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript)